# Casting PSMethod object to Func`2 in Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make the OAuth 2.0 service account for Google Drive example from https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts work in PowerShell 2.0.

```
$a= Add-Type -Path "D:\Google\OAuth\System.Web.Mvc.dll" -passthru
$b= Add-Type -Path "D:\Google\OAuth\DotNetOpenAuth.dll" -passthru
$c= Add-Type -Path "D:\Google\OAuth\Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.dll" -passthru
$d= Add-Type -Path "D:\Google\OAuth\Newtonsoft.Json.Net35.dll" -passthru
$e= Add-Type -Path "D:\Google\OAuth\Google.Apis.dll" -passthru

$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "<my service account email>"
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "<path to my certl>"
$certificate = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret", [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable);

$desc= [Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.GoogleAuthenticationServer]::Description

$provider = new-Object     Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth.AssertionFlowClient($desc, $certificate)
$provider.ServiceAccountId = $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL;
$provider.Scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"

$func= [Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth.NativeApplicationClient]::AuthorizeRequest

$auth = new-Object "Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator``1[Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth.AssertionFlowClient]"($provider, $func);
```

Unfortunately, that last new-object results in the following error message:

```
New-Object : Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "static System.Void AuthorizeRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest re
quest, string accessToken)", for "OAuth2Authenticator`1" to type "System.Func`2[Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNe
tOpenAuth.AssertionFlowClient,DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.IAuthorizationState]": "Cannot convert the "static System.Void Auth
orizeRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, string accessToken)" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSMeth
od" to type "System.Func`2[Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth.AssertionFlowClient,DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.I
AuthorizationState]"."
At line:1 char:19
+ $auth = new-Object <<<<  "Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator``1[Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.
DotNetOpenAuth.AssertionFlowClient]"($provider, $func);
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

It seems to be choking when trying to deal with passing that function in.

Does anyone know how to do this sort of wizardry with generics like this?

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining that the type of $func does not match the expected type of:

```
System.Func`2[Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth.AssertionFlowClient,DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.IAuthorizationState]
```

Or in C# speak:

```
Func<AssertionFlowClient, IAuthorizationState>
```

That is, the function must take an AssertionFlowClient and return an object that implements IAuthorizationState.  Are you sure about how you are creating $func?  I don't see a static AuthorizeRequest on the [docs page](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Authentication.OAuth2/DotNetOpenAuth/NativeApplicationClient.cs).